# Evaluation of a large integral

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a complicated large integral I want to evaluate (does not have a closed form, need an approximation), but *Mathematica* seems to keep "Running...". Is there any way to make *Mathematica* use more CPU power or anything to speed the calculations up?

The integral is the following:

```
Integrate[x (0.25 - x)^0.5*1/(Integrate[(1 - ((2 x/(1 - 2 x))*
  Cos[z])^2)^0.5, {z, 0, Pi}])*Sin[y]*
  (1 - ((2 x/(1 - 2 x))*Cos[y])^2)^0.5, {x, 0, 0.25}, {y, 0, Pi}]
```

Also, how long should I expect this to take?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What do you expect the final answer to be? I got the final answer= 0.005459

Comment: I'm expecting it somewhere between 0.005-0.007, so that is probably the correct value! How did you manage to get that? Did you just run the command the way I wrote it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole integration is complicated and I can not get it once like you. I break it down as follows:

```
f = (1 - ((2 x/(1 - 2 x))*Cos[z])^2)^(1/2)
```

and then do normal unbounded integration

```
int1 = Integrate[f,z]
```

and then find the bounded integration by simply substitute the boundary values of z

```
int11 = (int1 /. z -> Pi) - int1 /. z -> 0
```

and then do the NIntegrate

```
NIntegrate[
 x (0.25 - x)^0.5*1/(int11)*
  Sin[y]*(1 - ((2 x/(1 - 2 x))*Cos[y])^2)^(1/2), {x, 0, 0.25}, {y, 0, 
  Pi}]
(*0.00545945*)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Using `Assumptions` and a little simple substitution do can directly do that inner integral:

```
 $Assumptions = {0 < x < 1/4};
 r1 = Simplify[ 
       Integrate[(1 - (xx*Cos[z])^2)^(1/2), {z, 0, Pi},
       Assumptions -> {0 < xx < 1}]  /. xx -> (2 x/(1 - 2 x)) ]
```

then it turns out you can do the integral over y analytically as well:

```
 r2 = Simplify[Integrate[ x (1/4 - x)^(1/2)/
    (r1) Sin[y] (1 - ((2 x/(1 - 2 x)) Cos[y])^2)^(1/2) , {y, 0, Pi }   ]]
```

[image]

finally...

```
 NIntegrate[ r2  , { x, 0, 1/4 }]  (* 0.00545945 *)
```

Comment: +1 I kept thinking I was misreading the inner integral (aging eyes). I was surprised it didn't evaluate as is.  Seeing your answer, I'm still surprised it does not evaluate.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to get a closed form answer using this method?